Adaptive Filtering: Isn't the desired signal d(n) already known?

When applying an algorithm like LMS, for example, in order to updates the weight coefficients I need the error signal at time $e[n]$. Above is the summarized algorithm from Monson Hayes's book "Statistical Signal Processing and Modelling".
$$e[n] = d[n] - y[n],$$
where $d[n]$ is the desired signal and $y[n]$ is the filter output. But in order to calculate $e[n]$ it seems I need to know $d[n]$. But if I know $d[n]$, I already know the desired signal, so the whole algorithm becomes irrelevant.

Does that answer your question? https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/94203/rls-adaptive-filter-intuitive-explanation-of-the-so-called-desired-signal/94207#94207

This question is similar to: RLS adaptive filter intuitive explanation of the so-called desired signal. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The example from the link you provided above explains a situation in which the residual error is actually v(t), the speech signal from the near-end-speaker. This is a double talk scenario meaning both the near-end-speaker and the far-end-speaker talk. But let's take the single talk scenario (i.e. the near-end-speaker doesn't talk and let's also assume we have no noise coming from him, so v(t) = 0). So we just want to eliminate the echo from the far-end-speaker. e(t)=d(t)-y(t). In this case e(t) would be 0. So y(t)=d(t). But I already know d(t)!

So I guess I can rephrase my question like this: In system identification problems where the error signal e(t) has to be 0, isn't LMS irrelevant?

The LMS algorithm uses $d[n]$ as a training signal to adapt the filter coefficients iteratively. This process is critical for training and tuning the filter to achieve the desired performance. Once trained, the filter can operate without requiring $d[n]$, making the algorithm highly relevant for applications such as system modeling, noise cancellation, and signal equalization.
